# Multiple updates in firebase using nodejs as admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a user collections in my app, and now, we are creating a blacklist (blocked user List). and this is the new collection

```
BlackListByUser
  |
  |
  -- userIdBlackListOwber
         |
         |
         -- userIdBlocked
               |
                - name: "Suad"
                - username: "supersuad"
                - photo: "http://firebase......"
                - status: "S5"
```

through Firebase functions I detect user changes in these *(User Collection)* elements and I must update all the blackList no matter which user has it in their list.

```
exports.UpdateUserFromBlackList = functions.database.ref(`/User/{userId}`).onUpdate(event =>{
  ...
  db.ref(`BlackListByUser`).once('value').then(snapBlackList =>{
    snapBlackList.forEach(blackList =>{
       ...
       ...
       db.ref(`BlackListByUser/{blackList.key}/{userId}`).set(userInfo)
     })
  })
})
```

I think my solution is not the most efficient, considering that I have to go through all the elements of the BlackListByUser collection (as many blackList as users)

-nodejs as admin- How can I update all the user's items through all the blocking lists without iterating ? something like this

```
db.ref(`BlackListByUser/{NO_MATTER_KEY}/{userId}`).set(userInfo)
```

NOTE: Update() method is deprecate.

Comment: Quick answer below, but I'm not sure I understand the problem very well. Three separate questions: 1) What is the end-goal here? 2) And what specific inefficiency do you think there is in your current implementation? 3) What makes you say that "Update() method is deprecated"?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thnks for the help. 1. Update all reference without iterate blacklist by blacklist. 2. because i have to get blackList by blackList and then, for each one, look up the user id that I want to change (even,
I can go through all the lists without finding anything). 3. in a Warning firebase console. (not in this process).

Comment: "1. Update all reference without iterate blacklist by blacklist" That sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to update a node, you will have to know its full path. So if you don't know those yet, you will need to read or query the database to get the paths. Firebase does not have an equivalent of `UPDATE BlackListByUser SET .... WHERE ...`.

What could save you some bandwidth is keeping a separate list of just the information that you need to build the path. So if you just need the UIDs, then you could keep a list of just the UIDs with a `true` value (since Firebase Realtime Database will automatically delete keys without a value).